# Cannot get answer from the server

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I am making a simple backup program with **sockets** and **serverSocket** in java but my program is not working correctly.

**In short version:**

I have got two classes ClientModel and ServerModel and the problem is:

1. ClientModel `writeUTF` -> ServerModel `readUTF` // correctly received
2. ClientModel `writeObject` -> ServerModel `readObject` // correctly received
3. ServerModel is doing sth with that Object and ServerModel will send true or false via `writeUTF`
4. ClientModel is waiting for that String in method `readUTF` but the string never comes.

What is wrong in my flow? How can I fix it? I posted a code below. Thank you in advance.

**Longer version**

When user clicked on the button "connect to the server" in the Client GUI, then a clientModel send a String via `writeUTF()` which is correctly received by the server and after that a client immediately sent a object via `ObjectOutputStream` which is correctly received by the server. This object represent a user (login and password). My server is checking if that user is register in the server and if it is,the server will send a String `true` via `writeUTF` but the ClientModel cannot get that String. 
See my code:
**first method in the ClientModel**

```
public boolean autoryzacja() throws IOException {
    boolean wartosc = false;
    OutputStream strumien_wy = gniazdko.getOutputStream(); //socket was created before
    InputStream strumien_we = gniazdko.getInputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream strumien_obiektowy_wy = new ObjectOutputStream(strumien_wy);
    ObjectInputStream strumien_obiektowy_we = new ObjectInputStream(strumien_we);
    strumien_obiektowy_wy.writeUTF("AUTORYZACJA"); // correct
    strumien_obiektowy_wy.writeObject(uzytkownik); // correct
    String wynik = "";
    while(strumien_obiektowy_we.available()>0){ // I never be here 
    wynik = strumien_obiektowy_we.readUTF(); // problem here
    }
    if (wynik.equals("true")) {
        System.out.println("uzytkownik jest zarejstrowany na serwerze");
        wartosc = true;
    }
    return wartosc;
}
```

**method in the ServerModel**

```
public void run() {
     lista_uzytkownikow = pobierzUzytkownikow();
    String akcja = null;
    try {
        ObjectInputStream obiektowy_wej = new ObjectInputStream(gniazdko.getInputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream obiektowy_wyj = new ObjectOutputStream(gniazdko.getOutputStream());
        akcja = obiektowy_wej.readUTF(); // correct
        switch (akcja) {
        case "AUTORYZACJA":
            try {
                Uzytkownik user_temp = (Uzytkownik) obiektowy_wej.readObject(); // corrrect
                if (znajdzUzytkownika(user_temp)) {
                    obiektowy_wyj.writeUTF("JEST"); // problem here
                    System.out.println("jestem w case autoryzacja");
                } else {
                    obiektowy_wyj.writeUTF("BRAK");
                }
                break;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // System.out.println(akcja);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        // odbierzPlikWatkowy();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```